# SQL : Call information from another table based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

One is

[image: "passengers"]

that has information about the passenger in airlines, its small, just for the sake of representation

I have another table named

[image: "flights"]

, in this i storage information about the flight of each passenger

The idea is that if the passenger *did more than 5 flights* i need to display the passenger details

I stated a query in the table "flights" that counts *each time the passenger id repeats in the table*

```
SELECT passId, COUNT(passId) as numflights FROM flights GROUP BY passId;
```

Showing

[image: this table]

**Problem**
I need to update that query ir order that, if the number of flights for a passID is > 5, then it displays their detail information located in the table "passenger"

Comment: `Having count(*) > 5` after the group by, and join to pax table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use having an IN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM passengers 
WHERE passid IN (SELECT passId  as numflights FROM flights GROUP BY passId HAVING COUNT(passId) > 5)
```

if the numbers are high you need to join the tables

```
SELECT p1.* 
FROM passengers p1
INNER JOIN (SELECT passId  as numflights FROM flights GROUP BY passId HAVING COUNT(passId) > 5) p2
ON p1.passid = p2.passId
```

Comment: First query works fine, thank you! I will continue learning SQL

Answer (score 0):

Oner method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from passengers p
where (select count(*)
       from flights f
       where f.passid = p.passid
      ) > 5;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `flights(passid)`.  However, it is worth checking if this is actually faster than other alternatives, such as aggregating first and joining.